# how to do in line translation for transactional emails?

Tags: magento-1.9

i have an email which is sent at some point after an order is made on magento.

The email only contains a few lines of text.

The template was added to magento using an upgrade script in the core_email_template when the module was installed.

i would like to be able to change the content of the text of the email based on the store (i.e - german).
How can i implement translation for this email?

Comment: in short i need to translate the content of the email from core_email_template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be managed through

```
System > Transactional Emails.
```

The overview of email templates is empty by default, which means that all email templates are there on the filesystem but you have not created any override in the backend yet.

You can create a new override through the button `Add New Template`. In the new screen, select a template from the `dropdown`, change the locale if you want and hit the button Load Template.

All code will then be copied from the filesystem to the Magento Admin Panel, so you can modify it at your will.

you can also see [graphical view here](http://support.argoworks.com/entries/250517-Magento-How-do-I-modify-my-emails-How-do-I-modify-the-new-order-email-)

Comment: it is not an order email. It is a custom email. When i try to add new template - the above mentioned template is not present. Most probably because the dropdown is populated using templates from locale.

Comment: In template drop down you can find your custom one also

Comment: In the dropdown it is not present.

Comment: oh thats not correct way to use email template it should be at least come from one html file :( . you have to add new email template with new html file and called it when u need sorry

Comment: Is there some way we can do inline translation?

Comment: for translation dont know. but if u wish to edit directly you can change in `core_email_template` table. but this is also not good way. :(

Comment: pls dont forget to acpt my ans if its little useful to u

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension to translate Blocks and CMS Pages which might also work for emails. See the repo [here](https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_Translate/), there you will be able to see how the extension is made and if it does not work out of the box, add some code by yourself.